# Spring MVC 3, Tiles 2, and JQuery 1.7.1, JQuery-UI 1.8.16 - JQuery only works on 1 page?

Tags: jquery, jsp, spring-mvc

I am working through Pro Spring 3, and ch17 project introduces JQuery. I have edit.jsp that does both new and update depending on the "spring:url", and the jquery only works for the new? They are the same .jsp file with the same header, footer and menu just with a different title. The update page doesn't have the fancy buttons or the datepicker.

Comment: check your id of your html element...

Comment: the div id is "contactUpdate", will that make a difference even though they share the same page and components. One is a blank form and the JQuery works and one imports user data to perform updates in the same form yet the JQuery doesn't show up.

Comment: so you saying you have to buttons one updates and second one creates and one does not work? did you try to use javascript console? without source code i cannot just guess